# Spring RESTful Service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

Вообщем пишу веб-приложение на Spring. В приложение есть модель:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RSS_STREAM", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"link"}))
public class RssStream implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column
  private int id;

  @Column
  private String title;

  @Column
  @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL
  private String link;

  @Column
  @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL
  private String image;

  @Column
  private String description;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rssStream", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<RssFeed> feeds = new HashSet<RssFeed>();
  // Тут еще геттеры и сеттеры, но не привожу их, т.к. они стандартные
}
```

Другая таблица:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RSS_FEED")
public class RssFeed {

  @Id
  @Column
  private String title;

  @Column
  @URL
  private String link;

  @Column
  private String description;

  @Column
  private String content;

  @Column
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date pubDate;

  @Column
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date updateDate;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private RssStream rssStream;
}
```

Есть контроллер, который возвращает сериализованный объект `RssStream`, там есть все поля. Но одно но, мне не нужно, что бы там было поле `feeds`. Если убрать геттеры и сеттеры, то возникают проблемы при выборке из таблици `RssFeed`, что делать? Возможно ли как-то исключить поля из сериализатора.

Answer (score 3):

Вообщем в Jackson есть специальная аннотация: [JsonIgnoreProperties](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html). Она помогла решить проблему.

Comment: Есть также @JsonIgnore, если заинтересует есть интересный пост об их различиях http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/10/jackson-json-difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonignoreproperties-annotations/